# Fill in missing rows as NaN in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file that has daily precipitation data form 83 weather stations and 101 years per station.  I want to determine number of NaN per year for each station.

As a shortened example lets assume I only have one stations and only care about 1 years of data, 2009.

If I have this:

```
 station_id  year    month   1    2     3 
 210018      2009    1       5    6     8 
 210018      2009    2      NaN  NaN    6
 210018      2009    12      8    5     6
```

I want to get to this:

```
 station_id  year    month   1    2     3 
 210018      2009    1       5    6     8 
 210018      2009    2      NaN  NaN    6
 210018      2009    3      NaN  NaN    NaN 
 210018      2009    4      NaN  NaN    NaN
 210018      2009    5      NaN  NaN    NaN 
 210018      2009    6      NaN  NaN    NaN 
 210018      2009    7      NaN  NaN    NaN
 210018      2009    8      NaN  NaN    NaN 
 210018      2009    9      NaN  NaN    NaN
 210018      2009    10     NaN  NaN    NaN 
 210018      2009    11     NaN  NaN    NaN
 210018      2009    12      8    5      6
```

So my station needs 12 rows for all 12 months and a year to go along with each one.  Again I have 101 years in the real example.

I am trying to use this code:

```
df_indexed=df.set_index(['year'])
new_index=np.arange(1910,2011,1)
idx=pd.Index(new_index)
df2=df_indexed.reindex(idx, method=None)
```

but it returns a long error that ends with

`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd probably do is create a target MultiIndex and then use that to index in.  For example:

```
>>> target_ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.station_id.unique(),
    np.arange(1910, 2011, 1), np.arange(1,13)], 
    names=["station_id", "year", "month"])
>>> df = df.set_index(["station_id", "year", "month"])
>>> new_df = df.loc[target_ix]
>>> new_df.tail(24)
                        1   2   3
station_id year month            
210018     2009 1       5   6   8
                2     NaN NaN   6
                3     NaN NaN NaN
                4     NaN NaN NaN
                5     NaN NaN NaN
                6     NaN NaN NaN
                7     NaN NaN NaN
                8     NaN NaN NaN
                9     NaN NaN NaN
                10    NaN NaN NaN
                11    NaN NaN NaN
                12      8   5   6
           2010 1     NaN NaN NaN
                2     NaN NaN NaN
                3     NaN NaN NaN
                4     NaN NaN NaN
                5     NaN NaN NaN
                6     NaN NaN NaN
                7     NaN NaN NaN
                8     NaN NaN NaN
                9     NaN NaN NaN
                10    NaN NaN NaN
                11    NaN NaN NaN
                12    NaN NaN NaN
```

You can `.reset_index()` at this point if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

[edit]

THIS IS NOT A PANDAS ANSWER: question was not tagged pandas when I started answering, I will let it here because it can benefit someone.

Suppose you organize your data using a dict where the keys are a tuple of `(station_id, year, month)` and the values are an array of your data points - you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> data = defaultdict(lambda: [None, None, None])
>>> data[(210018, 2009, 3)]
[None, None, None]
```

You are probably reading from a file, I will not do all your homework for you - just give a few hints.

```
for line in file:
    station_id, year, month, d1, d2, d3 = parse_line(line)
    data[(station_id, year, month)] = [
        None if d == 'NaN' else float(d) for d in (d1, d2, d3)
    ]
```

Writing the `parse_line` function is left as an exercise for the reader.